# End-of-sentence space after \dots or \ldots or … with Xetex or Luatex

Tags: xspace

I do not understand how to type what we call in French *points de suspension* at the end of a sentence, like this...
I would like to create an \endldots command.
How could I redefine \ldots so that it behaves similarly to a regular dot with respect to anglosaxon-style end-of-sentence spacing, i.e. generates a bigger skip ? I tried \@…\space but it does not work (only work with Pdftex). (Note: in this post I used the Unicode character; of course I could just type 3 dots but obviously this is not what i want.)

Important : I'm compiling with **`Luatex`**.

```
 % !TEX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

But\@\ldots\space Even though,\@\ldots\space It still doesn't work. Too bad!

But\ldots\@\space Even though,\ldots\@\space It still doesn't work.\@ Too bad!

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newcommand{\susp}{…\spacefactor\sfcode`.\relax\space}
\renewcommand{\ldots}{…\space}

\begin{document}

But\susp Even though,\susp Now thanks to Egreg and David\ldots it works… like a charm\susp Thank you very much!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `\susp` (or whatever name you prefer) to state the wanted space factor at the end *and* to issue a space. This space will be removed at end paragraphs anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newcommand{\susp}{\ldots\spacefactor\sfcode`.\relax\space}
\newunicodechar{…}{\susp\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\xspaceskip=30pt % to better show the effect

But\susp But… But

BUT\susp But

\frenchspacing

But\susp But… But

BUT\susp But

\end{document}
```

[image]

With pdflatex we'd get

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much ! I like this
    \newcommand{\susp}{\ldots\spacefactor\sfcode`.\relax\space}
because it leaves the original character alone, we need it for middle-of-sentence context.

Answer (score 3):

`\@\ldots\space` (the last line below)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\parfillskip=0pt plus .5\textwidth % just to exagerate the space
Aaa\ldots Bbb.

Aaa\ldots\ Bbb.

Aaa\ldots\@ Bbb.

Aaa\ldots\@ Bbb.

Aaa\@\ldots\space Bbb.

\end{document}
```

---

In Unicode TeX the issue is rather different, `\ldots` resolves to the character `…` so you can give that character the same space factor code (`\sfcode`) as `.`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\sfcode`\…=\sfcode`\.
\begin{document}

\parfillskip=0pt plus .5\textwidth % just to exagerate the space
Aaa\ldots Bbb.

Aaa\ldots\ Bbb.

Aaa{\ldots} Bbb.

Aaa\ldots\space Bbb.

Aaa… Bbb.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you David. Sorry I forgot to mention, I'm not using pdftex. Your solution only works with pdftex.
As I mentioned in the original post, I already tried \@... but without success.

Comment: Admittedly, originally I had written \xspace instead of \space... which package you should know quite a bit about ;)

Comment: @VincentKrebs ah, lualatex (which applies for xelatex as well) answer added

Comment: Wow, \sfcode\`\…=\sfcode\`\ is incredibly simple, thank you ! If we use it, we have to define a middle-of-sentence character too.

Comment: @VincentKrebs `…\@` would stop the end of sentence space just as `.\@`  stops it with `.`